# Why are things far away moving away faster?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, space-expansion, universe

This is a really dumb question. But if things farther away are red shifted more, that literally means that the further away in time, things were moving away faster, but things closer to us arent moving as fast, which implies that things are actually slowing down?

Edit: To clarify my line of reasoning and the actual question here.
We know that things further away are expanding faster because the light is redshifted more. So, say, something at 5m ly away, will be moving less fast than something at 6m ly away. However, that data is also *stale* by 1m years. AKA, we don't know what the objects at 5m/6m light years away are doing *now*. For all we know, they could have to stopped expanding altogether, or slowed down expansion, reversed course even, its impossible to tell, because the light from *now* will only reach us 5m/6m years later. So sure, maybe things farther away appear to be moving away faster from us, but that is old/stale knowledge, and we don't actually know whats actually happening right now. Isn't this a glaring hole? Whats the current scientific communities ideas around this?

Comment: It's easy if you think of it the other way round.  Things moving away faster have travelled farther.

Comment: I should mention that General Relativity does not admit a well-defined notion of "present", so it doesn't really make sense to ask what objects far away are doing "now". The word "now" only has meaning in Relativity if we are choosing a particular set of coordinates on spacetime

Comment: Even everyday events, we see them in their past which is our present, for example, watching TV at a distance of 1 m, t'=d/c ~10^-8s  (retarded time).         https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retarded_time

Answer (score 1):

You can consider space as a grid:

[image]

Each grid-line is expanding by the same amount. So objects further away will move away even further :)

Also about the redshift: Things further away will take more time to arrive. This means they will undergo more of this expension of space, which causes things to be redshiftet more.

[Image source.](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DIWbc54u8k8c&psig=AOvVaw2jUBVR67z-EmqCZ2cfAt6E&ust=1640261171736000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAsQjRxqFwoTCICYoZav9_QCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAY)

Comment: Edited the question to clarify more clearly what i mean

Comment: Tamara Davis, of the Lineweaver & Davis pair that designed widely-used diagrams of horizons in relation to our past light-cone and the Hubble sphere which serve to show advantages of General Relativity over Special Relativity in cosmological contexts, has categorically stated that it is, literally, space which is (at least currently, in our observable region) expanding, and that that expansion doesn't serve as "a force or drag" carrying other objects (which are part of the universe) with it.  Their movement thru expanding space requires little-known factors, such as Dark Matter & Dark Energy.

Comment: It's the dots (stars?  galaxies?) in your diagrams that contradict what Davis was saying:  Without them, they might be more helpful.  See https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0310808

Comment: Someone, better with graphics than myself, might work an edit.

Answer (score 0):

The evolution of the universe depends on the evolution of scale factor $a(t)$. This is well-known result that
$$a_\text{em}=\frac{1}{1+z_\text{em}}$$
where $a_\text{em}$ is the scale factor when the light is emitted from distant galaxy and $z_\text{em}$ is red-shift. Here it is assumed that $a_\text{obs}=a_0=1$. Now, This shown the dependence of redshift on scale-factor. Now since $a$ is increasing; accelerating (as we believe and observe), We expect $z_\text{em}$ to be increasing as time increase.

Since light takes more and more time as we go further and further in space, it's clear that the light becomes more and more redshifted. This as you see doesn't mean that things are slowing down.

Comment: Edited the question to clarify more clearly what i mean

Answer (score 0):

In the context of general relativity, Weyl's postulate is that a privileged reference frame of spacetime can be defined and have a physical meaning. The most common notion to implement this notion is that of comoving coordinates*, where the spatial reference frame is attached to the average (spatial) positions of galaxies (or any large piece of matter that moves rather slowly).

In this choice of coordinates, one can ignore both time and the expansion of the Universe to focus on the shape of space (or more formally, of a spatial hypersurface at constant cosmological time).

Space in comoving coordinates is (on average) static. This is perfectly consistent with the fact that the Universe is expanding. A choice of coordinates is only a choice of numerical labels. It happens, according to the standard Big Bang model, that a certain choice is made to stick these labels in a very convenient way for formal calculations and also to think of the Universe as a static object. To come back to the very real expansion of the Universe, it is enough to remember the scale factor.(fr,wiki)

*https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comoving_and_proper_distances